# Error while I create dataproc workflow template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-vpc

I am trying to create a workflow template with the following command
`gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create $TEMPLATE_ID --region $REGION` but every time i try this I am getting this error:

[image]

If anyone has faced such issue can you please help me through this?
TIA

Comment: Is Dataproc API enabled for your VPC Service Control perimeter? On your console, Security > VPC Service Control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error, it sounds like an organization or project admin has applied a [VPC Service Controls Perimeter](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs) to your project that is preventing you from creating a workflow template. Generally, these restrictions apply at the API levels, so it's likely you will not be able to use other Cloud Dataproc API methods as well.

You should contact your project/org admin to understand what restrictions the VPC-SC perimeter enforces and how to gain access. The [VPC-SC Troubleshooter](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/troubleshooter) may be helpful in determining which policy is being violated by your request.